# Edit action is not doing anything on automapper

Tags: .net-core, controller, automapper

I´m using Visual Studio 2019, .net core 3.1 and automapper. My Edit action dont edit the record. I´ve seen tutorials but all are just of one action and I need to do a crud. Taking as example a usual edit action I´ve made this:

```
public class CustomerCountriesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public CustomerCountriesController(ApplicationDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        // GET: CustomerCountries
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()        
        {
            //CustomerCountries customerCountry = new CustomerCountries();
            var customerCountry = await _context.CustomerCountries.ToListAsync();            
            List<CustomerCountriesDto> countries = _mapper.Map<List<CustomerCountries>, 
                                                    List<CustomerCountriesDto>>(await _context.CustomerCountries.ToListAsync());
         
            return View(countries);
        }

public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            
            var customerCountries = await _context.CustomerCountries.FindAsync(id);
            var model = _mapper.Map<CustomerCountries, CustomerCountriesDto>(customerCountries);

            if (customerCountries == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            

            return View(model);
            //return View(customerCountries);
        }

        // POST: CustomerCountries/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]        
        //public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, [Bind("CustomerCountry")] CustomerCountries customerCountries)
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string customerCountry, CustomerCountriesDto customerCountriesDto)
        {
            if (customerCountry != customerCountriesDto.CustomerCountry)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    var CustomerCountries = _mapper.Map<CustomerCountriesDto, CustomerCountries>(customerCountriesDto);                    
                    _context.Update(CustomerCountries);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();                    
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!CustomerCountriesExists(customerCountriesDto.CustomerCountry))                    
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(customerCountriesDto);
        }


public class AutoMapping : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapping()
        {
            CreateMap<CustomerCountries, CustomerCountriesDto>();
            CreateMap<CustomerCountriesDto, CustomerCountries>();
        }
    }

public class CustomerCountries
    {
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Longitud máxima para el país: 50")]
        public string CustomerCountry { get; set; }

        public ICollection<CustomerRegions> CustomerRegions { get; set; }
    }

public class CustomerCountriesDto
    {
        public string CustomerCountry { get; set; }
    }
```

On startup

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

The id of the table is CustomerCounty

Can you tell me the correct way?

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: I have, but I am more confused now... edit only updates one registry, what a Collection has to do with it?

Comment: You have inner collections, but if edit doesn't do anything at all, perhaps it's not relevant.

Comment: ???? another person with some code please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I´ve found the solution thanks to an experienced developer that lead me through the issue and corrected my code from time to time (That is acctually really helping guys). Turns out that I was using a field as a PK: CustomerCountry... I wasn´t using and Id, when I changed the model, the update happened

```
var CustomerCountries = _mapper.Map<CustomerCountriesDto, CustomerCountries>(customerCountriesDto);
var country = _context.CustomerCountries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == CustomerCountries.Id);
country.CustomerCountry = customerCountriesDto.CustomerCountry;
                        _context.Update(country);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```